# Remove the Additional Row Created During write.table() Function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

While writing a data frame into a .txt file, it creates an additional row in the text file when you open it, but that extra row is not visible in the data frame and I have tried a lot of options to resolve it.
Examples I have used all the suggestions recommended like `trims()` & `writeLines()`.

But at the end whenever I write the file into .txt it always creates an additional row. Is there a way to resolve it.

I know in realistic terms all I have to do is open the txt file and delete the last row. But I am writing 100 of files in such a manner and it is not possible to do this for 100 txt files.

Attached is the code which I have used:

```
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# create a matrix of random numbers
data <- matrix(rnorm(5*3), nrow=5, ncol=3)

# create a vector of characters
chars <- letters[1:5]

# create a dataframe with random numbers and a character column
df <- data.frame(char_col=chars, data)

filename <- paste0("FileName_1,",".txt")
write.table(df, file = filename, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

Can someone help me out, I have tried everything and would love a solution for this. Is this even doable?

Attached is the snapshot of the issue after writing this. The yellow line shown below:

[image: picture of dataframe output with extra line on the end]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this an issue?

Comment: reading the source code of `write.table()`, it appears to use C for writing the table to file. It would probably be simplest to use a different function which doesn't do this, instead of writing files with `write.table()`, then rewriting them with something else

Comment: @georgemirandajr The issue is that, the file I write into .txt are then uploaded into a planning tool. So if I have 100 files all 100 of them need to be uploaded and the planning tool wont accept it if there is a line below it, so removing 100 lines by open each file is not easy. I hope that help. Do you have a solution to my problem?

Comment: @Mark What would be the recommendation to write files. Can .txt files be written in a different way I have writed `writeLInes()` also has the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write R code to throw away the last byte given that theres a LineFeed or some such there that you want to throw away

```
# open the connection to the file
in_filename <- "file.txt"
out_filename <- paste0("cleaned_",in_filename)
con_in <- file(in_filename, "rb")
con_out <- file(out_filename,"wb")
# get the total number of bytes in the file
size <- file.size(in_filename)

#Writing the output to local drive
writeBin(readBin(con_in,
        what = "raw",
        n = size - 2 ),
        con = con_out )

# close the connection
close(con_in)
close(con_out)
```

Comment: Can you explain what is happening here. Should I replace the `write.table()` function with `writeBin` function? It is a bit difficult to understand, could you explain. I am not an expert in R.

Comment: you have code to write out a text file (using write.table())  You need to further edit that file to throw away the last byte ; this code does that for a given file; it reads in all but the last byte, and then writes all the other bytes back out. Try it and see ?

Comment: So this should be wrote right before the `write.table()` function correct to ensure we can remove the last byte on the file? Or are we re loading the file which is written down back into R and performing this action?

Comment: I checked by 
# open the connection to the file
`in_filename <- df
out_filename <- paste0("cleaned_",in_filename)
con_in <- file(in_filename, "rb")
con_out <- file(out_filename,"wb")
# get the total number of bytes in the file
size <- file.size(in_filename)

writeBin(readBin(con_in,
        what = "raw",
        n = size - 1 ),
        con = con_out )`

`# close the connection
close(con_in)
close(con_out)`

This did not work at this line. `con_in <- file(in_filename,"rb")` says invalid description argument`

Comment: this assumes that you used write.table() and have a text file; it is to modify that text file.

Comment: guess you made a mistake with naming your in_filename. the symbol `df`, itself contains a filename or is it just a symbol df ?

Comment: It does not have the name of the file, it has the dataframe which I am writing to the local drive

Comment: I changed the code and assigned it as expected : 
`in_filename <- filename #This contains the name of the file not the dataframe`
`out_filename <- paste0("cleaned_",in_filename)`
`con_in <- file(in_filename, "rb")`
`con_out <- file(out_filename,"wb")`
`# get the total number of bytes in the file`
`size <- file.size(in_filename)`
`writeBin(readBin(con_in, what = "raw", n = size - 1 ),con = con_out )`

But when I write the output, it still creates another row at the end when I open the txt file. So I think this doesnt work.

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I think there are differences between windows and linux defaults; in windows you may need to remove the last two bytes, instead of only the last. so `n=size-2`

Comment: I think there might be a miss from my side, when I rant the line `con_in <- file(in_filename, "rb")` : R gives an error message saying `No Such Directory or File`. Do you want me to save the file first the directory and then run these codes which you suggested? Or Run them before the saving process. As of now I have run them before the saving process.

Comment: you have to have a file before you use my suggestion to further modify it.

Comment: Yes. You were correct N-2 worked, and even tried N-3 to see if it would remove one more character and it did. So this is spot on. If you correct the answer to n-2, I can update this as correct.